# AVL Trees:Maximimum and Minimum nodes if height is given?

Tags: data-structures, avl-tree

What is the **minimum** and **maximum** number of nodes on an **AVL tree** of height 6?

Comment: This is an easy question if you understand what an AVL tree is. I suggest that you go through your course material.

Comment: because i'm using python and c++ in implementation

Comment: @timgeb can u pls explain.. because i cant find

Comment: @user2530960 No, I won't accept your lie that you can't find an explanation of AVL trees online.

Comment: If I can find the answer to this question, why should i bother to postit here??

Comment: You are not supposed to "find" the answer. You are supposed to understand what an AVL tree is and then infer the answer to the question using your brain. Since you did not give us any specific point where you are stuck in your reasoning, we have nothing to work with here.

Comment: can't you explain how to get the answer? I dont have any clue!!!

Comment: don't you understand you telling me this question is too easy won;t help me.. isn't this website is for mutual help? or criticizing what is easy and what is not??

Comment: You clearly have a wrong idea about this website. It is not a homework help hotline for lazy students. We actually do help with homework, but only if the author shows own effort and has a specific question. "Give solution plz" is not a question.

Comment: The maximum is easy: it's a complete binary tree. For the minimum, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21347187/minimum-number-of-node-in-avl-tree.

Comment: You are missing the definition of AVL tree..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`n(h)` be the minimum number of nodes of an AVL tree of height `h`, then:

```
n(0) = 1
n(1) = 2
n(h) = 1 + n(h-1) + n(h-2)
```

as discussed [here](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/323/Syllabus/Trees/AVL-height.html).

A complete AVL tree is a complete binary tree, thus the maximum number of nodes is 2<sup>k + 1</sup> - 1, as discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141783/the-maximum-number-of-nodes-in-a-binary-tree-of-depth-k-is-2k-1-k-geq1).